# Accessing plugin settings in gutenberg

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I'm trying to build a gutenberg block (via plugin) that interfaces with a third-party api via credentials. I'm unsure how to, or even if I can, access a plugin's settings in gutenberg in order to grab a potential credentials field for use in the block. (I understand there's potential to put something in the editor's sidebar, but I need a persistent global setting that doesn't have to be set with every block.) Am I missing something in the documentation or is this not possible yet?

Comment: Have you tried using `wp_localize_script` to make the variables from, say, a settings page available to your block registration script (using `get_option()`)?

Comment: I haven't, and this seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WordPress way to access PHP variables with JavaScript is to use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

```
function wpse_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse', PATH_TO . 'script.js' );
  wp_localize_script( 'wpse', 'credentials', $credentials );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can access the credentials like

```
console.log( credentials );
```

Answer (score 4):

Now, I believe `wp_add_inline_script` is maybe the better option.
(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/)